# Microsoft Access Email Notification

Tags: ms-access

I currently have a Microsoft Database which records how much each department has used of each product. My tables are all linked and what I would like to do is:

When a product reaches 5 or less in its inventory field then I would like an email notification sent out for the product to be ordered.

I have a knowledge of Microsoft Access. However I'm not sure how I would be able to carry this out across to Microsoft Outlook etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would avoid trying to send mail via Outlook. Instead, I would use CDO (Collaboration Data Objects) to send the messages.

There is some VBA code available [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Email.aspx). (The article talks about sending email from Excel, but it works just as well from Access.)

Comment: I agree with using CDO, but most email servers today require authentication to send an email. The link you provided doesn't show those fields. Here's a link that includes the fields to do so: http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is create a query that returns the data when the inventory level falls below your trigger point.

Here's information on how Total Access Emailer sends emails from Access in a continuous manner: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Email/service/continuous.asp